# Mesh not showing in game engine after lattice deform

Tags: game-engine, parent

I'm trying to make a cube deform when pressing a button by using a lattice, so I've parented a simple cube to a lattice using the Lattice Deform option, but when I start the game engine it won't show anywhere.
The cube is new without any modifiers on it and the lattice surrounds it.
I've also tried to reinstall Blender but nothing changes, could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Lattice is not supported By the BGE.

Unsupported objects (curve, particle ,lattice ....) will not be converted to game objects when starting the game session. This means they will not present within the game.

Be aware children of unsupported objects will not appear as the parent is not present in the scene. I think this is your current situation.

I suggest to remove the lattice completely. At least unparent the cube from it.